# OpenCL, gcc and 19.10

Tags: dependencies, gcc, opencl

I'm trying to install OpenCL having recently upgraded to 19.10.  The system `gcc` is `9.2.1-9ubuntu2`.

However:

```
apt install mesa-opencl-icd
```

fails because it can't install `libclc-r600` or `libclc-amdgcn`

Diving down the rabbit hole yields:

```
libclc-amdgcn : Depends: libclang-common-8-dev but it is not going to be installed
libclang-common-8-dev : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04) but 9.2.1-9ubuntu2 is to be installed
               Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
```

How to proceed?